# Extending Enum in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I was hoping to reuse certain values in enum.
Any suggestions of how to achieve such functionality.

```
enum someEnum {
    a = 'Some String',
    b = 2,
};

enum extendedEnum {
    c = 'string',
    b = someEnum.b
}

type someEnumType<T extends someEnum> = T extends someEnum.a ? string :
    T extends someEnum.b ? number : never;

type extendedEnumType<T extends extendedEnum> =
    T extends extendedEnum.c ? string:          // Gives Error
    T extends extendedEnum.b ? number : never;  // Gives Error
```

Comment: note that if you declare new values to the same enum `enum someEnum { c = 'string', b = someEnum.b }` typescript will merge them together… but I would not recommend doing this as it will pollute the original enum

Comment: Unfortunately there's no way to do this as a `enum` i.e. have to use one of the `type` workarounds, and according to the TS Program Manager this is unlikely to change.  See https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17592#issuecomment-987332865

Answer (score 81, accepted):

### Currently, You can't extend enum in TypeScript

**Another option is to use type:**

```ts
enum Color1 {
    Red = "Red",
    Green = "Green"
}

enum Color2 {
    Yellow = "Yellow",
    Blue = "Blue"
}
```

define a new type named Colors :

```ts
type Colors = Color1 | Color2;
```

Then you can use it as below :

```ts
class AppComponent {
    public color: Colors;
    
    ngOnInit(): void {
      const Colors = { ...Color2, ...Color1 };
      this.color = Colors.Red; // Colors.Green or Colors.Yellow or Colors.Blue
    }
}
```

[**Stackblitz Here (Angular)**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/extending-enum-in-typescript)

[**Stackblitz Here (Typescript)**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-3xheja?file=index.ts)

Comment: `Colors.Red` does not work. `Colors` cannot be used like an enum, you get error ts2693: "'Colors' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here."

Comment: this merges types, not an enum

Comment: I am surprised that `Colors` is defined as type _and_ as a value, is that clean ? But @VictorP, regarding _"you get error ts2693..."_: It works without an error for me.

Comment: Similar to @kca, I seem to be able to achieve my goals without the `type Colors = Color1 | Color2;` line.

Answer (score 36):

I've just stumbled across this post from 2018 that explains how to do it with string based enums (see [the original comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17592#issuecomment-449440944)).

Here's an annotated / fruity version:

```
enum someEnum {
  Apple = 'Apple',
  Banana = 'Banana'
}

enum extendedEnum {
  Pear = 'Pear',
  Grape = 'Grape'
}

// The key seems to be to declare a type AND
// a const with the same name

type AllFruits = someEnum | extendedEnum;
const AllFruits = {...someEnum, ...extendedEnum};

let f: AllFruits = AllFruits.Grape;
```

The original poster (who, by all rights, seems to have been a contributor to TypeScript and knows what they're talking about) mentions that, using this method, you can't use something like `AllFruits.Grape` as a 'type literal', which means you can't do this:

```
// This error will appear: 
// 'AllFruits' only refers to a type, but is being used as a namespace here.

interface FruitBowl {
    fruit: AllFruits.Grape    
}
```

but this can be fixed with (something quite ugly) like:

```
interface FruitBowl {
    fruit: typeof AllFruits.Grape    
}
```

I guess this is one of the 'type workarounds' that others have mentioned.

(All credit to https://github.com/alangpierce)

Answer (score 20):

You could use a union in your type.

This works well for the task at hand. It allows to restrict `x` property to be only of values of `abc` or `def` enums. At the same time it allows using both enums as values.

```js
enum abc {
    a = 1,
    b = 2,
    c = 3
}

enum def {
    d = 4,
    e = 5,
    f = 6
}

type abcdef = abc | def;

let x: abcdef;

x = abc.a;  // Here we use enum as value
x = def.d;  // As well here.
```

Comment: Only works if you use the `enum` as a type, not as value.

Answer (score 8):

Union enum does not give type intellisense, but 'as const' object literal does.

```
const Color1 = {
    Red : "Red",
    Green : "Green"
} as const

const Color2 = {
    Yellow : "Yellow",
    Blue : "Blue"
} as const

const Colors = {...Color1, ...Color2} as const

type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];
type ColorsType = ValueOf<typeof Colors>

const c:ColorsType = Colors.Green  // use 'as const'

alert(c)
```

Try it [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=18&ssc=9&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAwiANiATgRhgXhgbwFAyEwBKApgCYwBcMARGebQDQFEDiKppY1dHXYWngC%20MAIYQYoSFDx5p0eElQAmLLlaEAmqUTIA7r1o69Ifc00wAQogCupIzftDREqeGhyFsBMhSTsHAA6EN9UNCYYEKCwlBVXSW85KABPAAcHADUxO1IAeQAzAB4AFQA%20dRKAbQBrUhSQApgSgF0AbjxUjKU-CBL0h2xs3MKirtJGntQIMq8PWGAqWL6B9WWg-m45HNIUKAAKYABKIA)

Comment: Thanks for the simple solution!  The `enum` declarations didn't work for us, but using `const` declarations simplified our code. Since we only need the string valuesn we don't even need the type declarations.

Comment: You are a total genius! thanks, works like a charm